# jquery treeview click on node or +

Tags: javascript, jquery, treeview

i use jquery treeview http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Treeview/treeview

i want to catch click on text node and do something
i use such code

> $('li').live('click', function(){
>       alert(this.id);
>       return false; });

but if i click on '+' it calls my js code, and then node expand. how can i blocked to call my js code? i know about call e.stopImmediatePropagation(); but how can i use it here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this
`$('li').live('click', function(event){ 
event.stopPropagation(); 
alert(this.id); 
return false; });`

Answer (score 0):

If you are still choosing tools for your task, you should try [jsTree](http://www.jstree.com/), a jQuery plugin with plenty of resources and configuration options.